# Complex graphs in $3$D

Tags: intuition, math-software

Does anyone have red-green $3$D software for plotting $4$D graphs in $3$D with $3$D glasses?

I've seen a $4$D hypercube done this way and it was very revealing.

Comment: for free oder do you want to buy a program?